# Trying to concat two dataframes on top of each other but having some troubles with index values and length mismatch

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I want to concatenate on top of each other. The DFs look like:

DF1 (3 columns, many rows in multiples of 3 duplicates)

```
    col1   col2   col3
0   A1     A2     A3
0   A1     A2     A3
0   A1     A2     A3
1   A4     A5     A6
1   A4     A5     A6
1   A4     A5     A6
```

DF2 (6 columns that are in multiples of 2 column headers and an empty col, many rows)

```
    col4  col5 'empty column' col4 col5 'empty column'
0    1    2                   3    4     
1    5    6                   7    8
```

Here are the steps that I've taken:

1) Transpose DF1 by:

```
DF1 = DF1.reset_index().transpose()
```

I was hoping that transposing will match the 3 duplicates to the col4, col5 and empty column of DF2

2) concat the two DFs:

```
DF3 = pd.concat([DF1, DF2], ignore_index=True)
DF3.to_excel('list.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```

However, this will simply output DF1 with index also transposed even with reset_index:

```
0   0   0   1   1   1
A1  A1  A1  A4  A4  A4
A2  A2  A2  A5  A5  A5
A3  A3  A3  A6  A6  A6
```

I am sure I did the transpose and/or concat wrong but I cannot pinpoint where. Am I missing something?

Edit)

The expected output should be:

```
A1    A1    A1    A4    A4    A4
A2    A2    A2    A5    A5    A5
A3    A3    A3    A6    A6    A6
col4  col5        col4  col5
1     2           3     4
5     6           7     8
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: What is your expected outcome? BTW, `reset_index` keeps the original indices. You can use `reset_index(drop=True)` to get rid of them in your new df.

Comment: updated the post with the expected outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create same columns values in each DataFrame:

```
df1 = DF1.reset_index(drop=True).T
df2 = DF2.copy()
df2.columns = np.arange(len(df2.columns))

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    0   1    2   3   4    5
0  A1  A1   A1  A4  A4   A4
1  A2  A2   A2  A5  A5   A5
2  A3  A3   A3  A6  A6   A6
3   1   2  NaN   3   4  NaN
4   5   6  NaN   7   8  NaN
```

If need columns from `DF2` to row between:

```
df1 = DF1.reset_index(drop=True).T
df2 = DF2.copy()
df2.columns = np.arange(len(df2.columns))

#convert columns to one row DataFrame
df3 = DF2.columns.to_frame().T
df3.columns = np.arange(len(df3.columns))

df = pd.concat([df1, df3, df2], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
      0     1    2     3     4    5
0    A1    A1   A1    A4    A4   A4
1    A2    A2   A2    A5    A5   A5
2    A3    A3   A3    A6    A6   A6
3  col4  col5       col4  col5     
4     1     2  NaN     3     4  NaN
5     5     6  NaN     7     8  NaN
```

If need columns from `DF2` in top solution is set columns of `df1` by `DF2` columns:

```
df1 = DF1.reset_index(drop=True).T
df1.columns = DF2.columns

df = pd.concat([df1, DF2], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  col4 col5      col4 col5     
0   A1   A1   A1   A4   A4   A4
1   A2   A2   A2   A5   A5   A5
2   A3   A3   A3   A6   A6   A6
3    1    2  NaN    3    4  NaN
4    5    6  NaN    7    8  NaN
```

Disadvantage of solution is get duplicated columns names, so if seelct one column get all columns with dulicated columns names:

```
print (df['col4'])
  col4 col4
0   A1   A4
1   A2   A5
2   A3   A6
3    1    3
4    5    7
```

Comment: It almost works, but the col4, col5, empty col part seems to be the index of DF2 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ....)

Comment: @BongKyoSeo - Not sure if understand, if want concat columns together is necessary for each DataFrame same index values. Can you explain more?

Comment: I checked DF2 after df2.columns = np.arange...  and the column names were replaced by 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...  and hence why col 4, col5, were replaced by these numbers.

Comment: @BongKyoSeo - yes, it is necessary, because if not data should be not aligned on top of each other.

Comment: hmm, if that is the case, is there a way to insert a row in between df1 and df2, then fill out the row with col4, col5, and an empty space until the end of column? col4, col5, and the empty space are the same for all the columns of three.

Comment: @BongKyoSeo - Do you think my second solution?

Comment: I tried the second solution which resulted in the col4, col5, " " being replaced by 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ....  I just checked df2 before np.arange and it has col4, col5, and whatnot, but when I print df2 after np.arange, they are replaced with 0, 1, 2, ..

Comment: @BongKyoSeo - yes, it is necessary, but columns is converted to separate DataFrame `df3` and concat together with `df = pd.concat([df1, df3, df2], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Never mind, I moved lines with df3 to the top and it solved the problem. Thank you!